# Docker Advice: PHP Application

Tags: php, docker, nginx

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I'm containerizing our old legacy applications.

I'm not sure what the best container setup would be, so far I'm looking at creating the following.

```
Container 1: Nginx
Container 2: PHP-FPM + Web Application (Composer+Node)
Container 3: PHP-FPM + REST API (Composer)
Container 4: PHP-FPM + Mobile API (Composer)
```

The issue that I have is relating to the application source. Containers 3 and 4 also need the source that is in container 2. Container 1 needs the source of all the other containers to serve static content.

For dev this is not an issue as you just mount the local source. For production would I use a top level volume in docker-compose.yml to include the source from the other volumes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just `COPY` the application sources into all the images. At this point, anything else is an example of [premature optimization](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization), which would make the overall infrastructure more complicated and more fragile.

Disk space costs next to nothing nowadays. On the other hand, the simplicity and robustness of the infrastructure are extremely valuable.

Think about ways to optimize your image sizes only after it causes real problems.

Comment: Thanks for the info, the total application size is pretty small. 700MB in total for all 3.

Comment: Sorry for duplicate comment. Would you recommend having the image include/build all the composer+node packages? If so how would the Nginx web server get access to these packages if they included static content?

Comment: Yes, I personally would start with the simplest solution first — just `COPY` all the dependencies into all the images including `nginx`. There's no magic way `nginx` would read them from another container, they have to be present there too. That means you'd have to build a custom `nginx` image too.

Comment: Thought so. Thanks for the advice. 

Comment: @Danny121 note that absolute paths to sources must match in both `nginx` and `php` containers.

Comment: Another possibility, depending on what you're actually doing, is to run three different containers off of the same image, overriding the command so the containers do different things but using the same code base.